# Subring of $\text{Mat}_n(Z_m)$ is commutative if $x^2=0 \implies x=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Let $A$ be subring of $\text{Mat}_n(Z_m)$. Suppose, for $x\in A$, $x^2=0$ implies $x=0$.
**Claim** A is commutative.

**Attempt**
$A$ is finite ring, hence Artinian. 
If it is possible to claim that Jacobson Radical is $0$,
then by Weddenburg-Artin, result might follow.
(I did not finish the argument yet, I am not sure if this path is okay.)

I am not sure how to use the information $x^2=0 \implies x=0$.
Also, I am not sure where to use being subring of $\text{Mat}_n(Z_m)$ (except being finite).

A brief explanation might help a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: If $n>1$ and $m$ is odd, then the elementary matrix $E_{1,1}$ generates a subring that satisfies the hypothesis $x^2=0\implies x=0$, but that is not a field. So you can't hope to apply Wedderburn in general.